# Need Outlook.Items.Find() result's index in Outlook.Items collection

Tags: c#, outlook, indexing, find, contacts

Is there anything in the returned object from Items.Find() that indicates said object's position in the collection on which Find() was called?

```
Outlook.Application App = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MAPIFolder contactFolder = App.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
    Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
Outlook.Items contactItems = contactFolder.Items;

Outlook.ContactItem matchItem = contactItems.Find(
    "@SQL=urn:schemas:contacts:cn LIKE '" + searchString + "%'");
```

At this point I need `matchItem`'s index in the `contactItems` collection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference pointed to by `matchItem` should be equal to the reference in the Items collection. So, you should be able to go through the Items collection and find the index by referential equality. You'll need the items in a strongly-typed List:

```
//Change how you're accessing the items of this folder
//the new list should have the same references as the Items property
var contactItems = contactFolder.Items.OfType<Outlook.ContactItem>().ToList();
...
//then use the List's built-in IndexOf() function:
var index = contactFolder.IndexOf(matchItem);
```

Comment: If IndexOf() here is linear, what is the benefit of this method over rolling my own search and bypassing Find() altogether?

Comment: You don't have to roll your own search? Unless you're paid by the line of code, I'd use what the framework gives you and move on to the next dev item.